# Coreos ignition with remote config fails because of the network

Tags: networking, vmware, coreos, vsphere, coreos-ignition

I'm trying to boot my coreOS ova image in VSphere by using customize ignition data which is allocated in a remote file (in S3 amazon). Unfortunatelly I get always the same error:

```
A start job is running formation (disks) ignition[380]: Get https//s3..... ignition.json: dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

My ignition file has the following data:

```
{
    "networkd": {
      "units": [
       {
         "contents": "Match]\nName=eth0\n\n[Network]\nDNS=8.8.8.8\nAddress=192.168.1.1/24\nGateway=192.168.1.1",
         "name": "eth0.network"
  }
  ]
    },
    "ignition": {
        "version": "2.1.0",
        "config": {
            "replace": {
                "source": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/.../ignition.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me??

Many thanks!
Jorge

Comment: My problem was because I deployed Vsphere ESXi in VMware and it needs to setup promiscuous mode in the host VM. If we do not set up this network feature, guest VMs do not get internet access or external access.